# Can I avoid the volatile read in double checked locking once initialized like this?

Tags: java, concurrency

By using a volatile boolean that is read only if the instance is null, can I avoid the default/frequent volatile read once the instance is initailized like so? Havent seen anyone recommend double checked locking like this, but seems to avoid volatile reads once fully initialized...

```
public class Singleton {

   private static volatile boolean initialized = false;
   private static Object lock = new Object();
   private static Singleton instance;

      public static Singleton getInstance(){
           if(instance != null) return instance;
           if(!initialized){
                synchronized(lock){
                   if(!initialized){
                       instance = new Singleton();
                       initialized = true;
                   }
                }
           }
           return instance;

       }
```

}

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, you cannot. If thread A has reached the synchronized block and is executing the

```
instance = new Singleton();
```

line, a thread B entering your function could see `instance` as initialized before thread A has finished constructing the object. So you risk having thread B try to work on a partially constructed object.

See the [DLCP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-checked_locking#Usage_in_Java) article for variations and explanations on this pattern.

Answer (score 1):

Your optimization attempt is not only premature, but also fruitless, quoting [Are volatile variable 'reads' as fast as normal reads?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1090311):

> On an x86, there is **no additional overhead** associated with volatile reads.

Comment: on virtually all the hardware reads are cheap if they hit the cache, otherwise no.

Answer (score 0):

If you want lazy instantiation but concerned about performance, use "inner class" approach - it is cleaner and shorter (and a tiny bit more efficient as well). Something like that:

```
public class Singleton {

    private static class SingletonHolder {
        private static final Singleton instance = new Singleton();
    }

    public static Singleton getInstance(){
        return SingletonHolder.instance;
    }

}
```

The trick is that instance is created during initialization of the inner class - that will happen when class is first referenced, which is first call to `getInstance()`.
BTW - avoid such "static" singletons, unless there are truly good reasons to use them.

Comment: inner class is actually worse as volatile read is practically free. inner class just increases the boot load time and creates useless stuff in the perm gen + extra boiler plate code.

Comment: @bestss - unless only several classes and not 95% of your code are singletons perm gen is not an issue; and why should boot time be longer when using typical synchronized block? Also - do you think that double locking is lesser bit of boilerplate code?

Comment: I tend to have something like LazyReference<T> that takes a Callable<T> in the c-tor and that's it, you can't do that with an explicit class to provide a static final field. The boot time is longer b/c the class has to be loaded off the disk (decompressed, verified etc). It's an extra call to the classloader which tends to result in looking up parent+system and bootstrap classloaders etc.

Comment: Of course, you can argue that simplifying the code w/ Callable addes another class :D

Comment: @bestsss - ah, that's nice; isolates "singleton" aspect from construction of the class. I also tried some benchmarks - `getInstance()` with "inner class" approach takes ~50% less time than with "double locking", but in absolute figures it's just some nanoseconds. So yeah, `LazyReference` looks attractive.

Comment: side note on dedicated class to initialization: if any exception is thrown that would result in ExceptionInInitializerError basically preventing any attempt to re-try the operation. The only way to recover is some hot redeploy, i.e. abandoning the classloader. Usually if there is no chance to fail the initialization, it'd be better off w/ eager one.

Comment: @bestsss - that's a valid concern, but there are not only web apps in this world; sometimes fail-fast behaviour is not so bad.

Comment: I do not get the web page remark. I am doing a lot middleware, though

Answer (score 0):

volatile read is (almost) free on most hardware, volatile write is expensive, though... So why bother?

The short answer is no. between `instance = new Singleton()` and `initialized = true` on a weak memory model where stores can be reordered a reader might see an uninitialized Signleton.
on x86 and sparc TSO no store-store reorder but on ARM and IA64 it does happen.