# FutureTask Implementation re-read state to prevent leaked intterupts

Tags: java

Here is the implementation of some methods of `FutureTask` in Java:

`run` method:

```
public void run() {
    if (state != NEW ||
        !UNSAFE.compareAndSwapObject(this, runnerOffset,
                                     null, Thread.currentThread()))
        return;
    try {
        Callable<V> c = callable;
        if (c != null && state == NEW) {
            V result;
            boolean ran;
            try {
                result = c.call();
                ran = true;
            } catch (Throwable ex) {
                result = null;
                ran = false;
                setException(ex);
            }
            if (ran)
                set(result);
        }
    } finally {
        // runner must be non-null until state is settled to
        // prevent concurrent calls to run()
        runner = null;
        // state must be re-read after nulling runner to prevent
        // leaked interrupts
        int s = state;
        if (s >= INTERRUPTING)
            handlePossibleCancellationInterrupt(s);
    }
}
```

`cancel` Method:

```
public boolean cancel(boolean mayInterruptIfRunning) {
    if (!(state == NEW &&
          UNSAFE.compareAndSwapInt(this, stateOffset, NEW,
              mayInterruptIfRunning ? INTERRUPTING : CANCELLED)))
        return false;
    try {    // in case call to interrupt throws exception
        if (mayInterruptIfRunning) {
            try {
                Thread t = runner;
                if (t != null)
                    t.interrupt();
            } finally { // final state
                UNSAFE.putOrderedInt(this, stateOffset, INTERRUPTED);
            }
        }
    } finally {
        finishCompletion();
    }
    return true;
}
```

`handlePossibleCancellationInterrupt` method:

```
private void handlePossibleCancellationInterrupt(int s) {
    // It is possible for our interrupter to stall before getting a
    // chance to interrupt us.  Let's spin-wait patiently.
    if (s == INTERRUPTING)
        while (state == INTERRUPTING)
            Thread.yield(); // wait out pending interrupt

    // assert state == INTERRUPTED;

    // We want to clear any interrupt we may have received from
    // cancel(true).  However, it is permissible to use interrupts
    // as an independent mechanism for a task to communicate with
    // its caller, and there is no way to clear only the
    // cancellation interrupt.
    //
    // Thread.interrupted();
}
```

I know these methods are implemented this way to prevent the run method to finish before interrupting the thread in `cancel` method finished and the state has changed from `interrupting` to `interrupted` but I can't understand two things:

Why these lines of code in run method:

```
int s = state;
if (s >= INTERRUPTING)
    handlePossibleCancellationInterrupt(s);
```

could not be changed to this one:

```
if (state == INTERRUPTING)
    handlePossibleCancellationInterrupt(state);
```

So I can't understand two things:

1. What is the effect of this statement `int s = state`
2. Why `state >= INTERRUPTING` statement can not be changed to this one `state == INTERRUPTING`

Comment: FYI, your source code looks outdated. [Here is Java 11](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/master/src/java.base/share/classes/java/util/concurrent/FutureTask.java), and [here is Java 16 pre-release](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk16/blob/master/src/java.base/share/classes/java/util/concurrent/FutureTask.java).

Comment: @BasilBourque Where is the difference they are exactly the same.

Comment: Not the same. Yours calls `UNSAFE`. Java 11 & 16 do not. And there may be other changes, such as [8197531: Miscellaneous changes imported from jsr166 CVS 2018-04](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/commit/cdd36df3637b1bd1f1528a82a7efb24c39dad70a).

Comment: Thanks for your precious information, but the part I mentioned in the question are the same. I mean this part `int s = state;
if (s >= INTERRUPTING)
    handlePossibleCancellationInterrupt(s);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### 1. Effect of `int s = state`

`state` being a `volatile` variable, must be the predominant reason for assigning it to `s`. This way, we can avoid an additional costlier volatile read access within the `if` statement.

The links [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1090311/are-volatile-variable-reads-as-fast-as-normal-reads) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4633866/is-volatile-expensive) discusses about volatile read performance.

### 2. `state >= INTERRUPTING`

May be initially there were discussions to reset the `interrupted` status of the thread in `handlePossibleCancellationInterrupt()`.

Below block commented in `handlePossibleCancellationInterrupt()`

> ```
>     // We want to clear any interrupt we may have received from
>     // cancel(true).  However, it is permissible to use interrupts
>     // as an independent mechanism for a task to communicate with
>     // its caller, and there is no way to clear only the
>     // cancellation interrupt.
>     //
>     // Thread.interrupted();
> ```

Clearing the interrupt should have happen, even in case the state is `INTERRUPTED`.